# Evaluate SMOTE and RandomUnderSampling different strategies

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working in pandas in Python with a data frame `df`. I am carrying out a classification task and have two imbalanced classes `df['White']` and `df['Non-white']`. For this reason, I have built a pipeline that includes both SMOTE and RandomUnderSampling.

This is what my pipeline looks like:

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('smote', over),
        ('random_under_sampler', under),
        ('classification', knn)
    ])
```

And these are the exact steps:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor',
                 ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                                   transformers=[('knnimputer', KNNImputer(),
                                                  ['policePrecinct']),
                                                 ('onehotencoder-1',
                                                  OneHotEncoder(), ['gender']),
                                                 ('standardscaler',
                                                  StandardScaler(),
                                                  ['long', 'lat']),
                                                 ('onehotencoder-2',
                                                  OneHotEncoder(),
                                                  ['neighborhood',
                                                   'problem'])])),
                ('smote', SMOTE()),
                ('random_under_sampler', RandomUnderSampler()),
                ('classification', KNeighborsClassifier())])
```

I would like to evaluate the different `sampling_strategy` within SMOTE and RandomUnderSampling. Can I do this directly within GridSearch when tuning the parameters? For now, I have written the following `for loop`. This loop does not work (`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`).

```
strategy_sm = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
strategy_un = [0.15, 0.30, 0.50]
best_strat = []

for k, n in strategy_sm, strategy_un:
    over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=k)
    under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=n)
    model = Pipeline([
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('smote', over),
        ('random_under_sampler', under),
        ('classification', knn)
    ])
    mode.fit(X_train, y_train)
    best_strat.append[(model.score(X_train, y_train))]
```

I am not very proficient in Python, and I suspect there is a better way to do this. Also, I'd like the `for loop` (if this is indeed the way to do it), to visualize the difference performance for combinations of `sampling_strategy`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you want to undersample after you oversample in the same pipeline like this? Your code won't independently evaluate SMOTE and RandomUnderSampling in your pipeline.

Comment: I am following this [guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/), that mentions: _The original paper on SMOTE suggested combining SMOTE with random undersampling of the majority class._ I have checked and indeed they do suggest this. You run into all sorts of issues if you do not insert the two samplers separately, unfortunately

Comment: Sounds good. My comment was primarily about the phrasing, which I took as wanting to evaluate independently.

Comment: I see now. Yes, it makes sense to not evaluate them separately. I had tried to combine them into a pipe. But I kept getting `TypeError: All intermediate steps of the chain should be estimators that implement fit and transform or fit_resample`.
I think it is necessary to make a flat pipeline having the over-sampling followed by the under-sampling since there is an ambiguity because the imbalanced-learn pipeline defines both fit/transform and fit_resample.

Comment: You probably need to use an imblearn pipeline, as the sampler interfaces may not conform to scikit-learn pipeline expectations

Comment: @NickBecker Indeed, I forgot to specify that I have used Pipeline from imbalanced learning. There was a good explanation of why this does not work somewhere here (I cannot remember where)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of how you could compare the classifier's accuracy for different parameter combinations using 5-fold cross-validation and visualize the results.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# generate some data
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_features=20, random_state=42)

# define the pipeline
estimator = Pipeline([
    ('smote', SMOTE()),
    ('random_under_sampler', RandomUnderSampler()),
    ('classification', KNeighborsClassifier())
])

# define the parameter grid
param_grid = {
    'smote__sampling_strategy': [0.3, 0.4, 0.5],
    'random_under_sampler__sampling_strategy': [0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
}

# run a grid search to calculate the cross-validation
# accuracy associated to each parameter combination
clf = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=estimator,
    param_grid=param_grid,
    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
)

clf.fit(X, y)

# organize the grid search results in a data frame
res = pd.DataFrame(clf.cv_results_)

res = res.rename(columns={
    'param_smote__sampling_strategy': 'smote_strategy',
    'param_random_under_sampler__sampling_strategy': 'random_under_sampler_strategy',
    'mean_test_score': 'accuracy'
})

res = res[['smote_strategy', 'random_under_sampler_strategy', 'accuracy']]

print(res)
#   smote_strategy random_under_sampler_strategy  accuracy
# 0            0.3                           0.5  0.829471
# 1            0.4                           0.5  0.869578
# 2            0.5                           0.5  0.899881
# 3            0.3                           0.6  0.809269
# 4            0.4                           0.6  0.819370
# 5            0.5                           0.6  0.778669
# 6            0.3                           0.7  0.708259
# 7            0.4                           0.7  0.778966
# 8            0.5                           0.7  0.768568

# plot the grid search results
res_ = res.pivot(index='smote_strategy', columns='random_under_sampler_strategy', values='accuracy')
sns.heatmap(res_, annot=True, cbar_kws={'label': 'accuracy'})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Flavia. I keep running into the following error: `ValueError: The specified ratio required to remove samples from the minority class while trying to generate new samples. Please increase the ratio.`

Comment: I am training `clf` on X_train and y_train. These below are values counts for y_train:

 - Non-white    34707
- White        15718

Comment: Try using `StratifiedKFold` as in the updated code that I just posted.

Comment: I have tried to experiment with a wide (`[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]`) range of ratios for both (just to explore) and ignored the error. In the end, I have obtained a graph that showed that the only productive combinations were [0.5, 0.6, 0.7] for both over and under sampler. **Edit**  I will try the code and report back

Comment: The fix does not work and returns the same error (but also the same end result) for the previous code. To me, it makes sense, however. Simply, the data allows for a small combination of ratios. I am not going above 0.7 since I'd lie to avoid overfitting. Thank you for your effort. I will try to find a way to straight-up ignore the error and get the final graph without the red errors before